# Flutter : Mysql how to pass row data from ListView to Card

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

Found solution :
For each element of BddAdresseClient
elementAt(1)

return ListView.builder(
itemCount: snapshot
.data!.length, // mettre le ! pour tester le null
itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
return affClient(
snapshot.data![currentIndex], context);

Widget affClient(List infoClient, BuildContext context) {
return new ListTile(
title: new Card(

Text(
infoClient.elementAt(1).toString(),

Comment: Is this a question or a question with an answer?